# pull details from local database

Tags: swift, core-data

I want to pull details from local database but when I do the necessary operations, it returns null as a result. I can't understand where I went wrong.

```
var chosenCar=""
var chosenCarId : UUID?
```

the arrays I created, I transfer data to these arrays, there is no problem with that, I did a test

```
if chosenCar != "" {
        //core data
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                    
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CarsInformation")
                    let idString = chosenCarId?.uuidString
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", idString!)
        
      
                    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        
  
       
        
        do {
           
   
                      let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                       
                       if results.count > 0 {
                           
                           for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                              
                               
                               if let name = result.value(forKey: "models") as? String {
                                   modelTextField.text = name
                               }

                               if let year = result.value(forKey: "year") as? Int {
                                 
                                   yearTextField.text = String(year)
                                   
                               }
                               
                               if let price = result.value(forKey: "price") as? Int {
                                   priceTextField.text = String(price)
                               }
                               
                               if let imageData = result.value(forKey: "image") as? Data {
                                   let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                   imageView.image = image
                               }
                            
                               
                           }
                       }
           

                   } catch{
                       print("error")
                   }
                   
                   
               } else {
                   
                   modelTextField.text = ""
                   priceTextField.text = ""
                   yearTextField.text = ""
               }
```

After doing these operations, I can't get the result I want.

Comment: How do you know chosenCarId is not nil?

Comment: when i print i get the result but when it goes in and out of the loop the result is 0

Comment: Where do you print the results, right before the loop?

Comment: modelTextField.text I get a print(chosenCar) result when I print before but when I put print on the line after modelTextField I get 0 result

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing but I would suggest that you either debug your code or add a number of print statements, for example print chosenCarId before you create the predicate, print results.count after you have executed the fetch etc.